# Commutator bertween shift operator and "position" operator

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, quantum-mechanics

I was studying the shift operator in quantum mechanics from wikipedia and in the [commutator section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_operator_(quantum_mechanics)#Commutator_with_position_operator) explains that for a shift operator $\hat T(x)$ and a position operator $\hat x$, the commutator $\left [\hat T(x),\hat x\right]=x\hat T(x)$, but doesn't make sense to me, because it seems like you are shifting *"eternally"* by the function $x$. In the [wikipedias's position operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position_operator#Eigenstates), it indicates that the **eigenfunction** of $\hat x$ is the Dirac delta function $\delta_a(x)$ centered at $a$, so I did the algebra as follows:

For a shift of $h$-units $\hat T_h$ (using calculus notation):

$$\left[x,T_h \right]\delta_a(x)=x(T_h(\delta_a(x))-T_h(x\delta_a(x)) $$

$$=x(\delta_a(x+h))-T_h(a\delta_a(x))=(a-h)\delta_a(x+h)-a\delta_a(x+h)$$

$$=a\delta_{a+h}(x)-h\delta_{a+h}(x)-a\delta_{a+h}(x)=-h\delta_{a+h}(x)=-hT_h(\delta_a(x))$$

$$\Rightarrow \left[x,T_h \right]=-hT_h$$

So, if we subsitute $h$ for $x$, the result would be the same as explained in the source, but one is a scalar multiplication, and the other is point-wise multiplication of two functions. If we do the substitution, by this other source about [shift operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_operator#Functions_of_a_real_variable), the conmmutator applied to Dirac delta should be:

$$\left[x,T_x \right]\delta_a(x)=x\delta_a(ex)-T_x(a\delta_a(x))$$
$$=x\delta_a(ex)-a\delta_a(ex)={a\over e}\delta_a(ex)-a\delta_a(ex)$$
$$=a\left({1-e\over e}\right)\delta_a(ex)=a\left({1-e\over e}\right)T_x(\delta_a(x))$$
$$\Rightarrow \left[x,T_x \right]=a\left({1-e\over e}\right)T_x$$

Answer (score 2):

Your confusion comes from the fact that you are merging two different operators together.

The first derivation you made is correct, i.e. $[x,T_h] = hT_h$ (by the way, you needn't consider the Dirac delta eigenfunctions, the relation is valid for any function of $x$). However, it is to be kept in mind that $T_h = e^{h\partial_x}$ can be interpreted as a translation/shift operator only when $h$ is a fixed/constant quantity.

The second relation is almost correct; it should be $[x,T_x] = (e-1)xT_x$ (which can be also applied not only to Dirac delta functions but to any function of $x$), since $T_x = e^{x\partial_x}$ is a scaling operator $-$ the general case is given by $e^{tx\partial_x}f(x) = f(e^tx)$.

In conclusion, we are talking about two different operators, such that the constant shifting parameter $h$ in $T_h$ cannot be merely replaced by the (non-constant) variable $x$ without changing its nature.

Comment: That's what I said... So what interpretation is right? Quantum or mathematician?

Comment: There is no contradiction between QM and maths : there are two different operators, with different effects (translation vs scaling), used in different contexts. Keep in mind that a *shift operator* is not always a translation operator in mathematics (even if it corresponds to its most simple case), but a general term for all exponentiated vector fields as $e^{t\beta(x)\partial_x}$.

Comment: in both cases means translation of the function. The quantum approach is true if we decide to translate $\psi$ by $\langle \hat x\rangle$, which seems false otherwise.